# why the load function is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

This code is not working not only this but when ever i use the this->load->library('email') or something its showing error as

```
"message": "Undefined property: App\\Controllers\\Epicureser1::$load",
```

this is the code which i used currently

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']             = 100;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;
$this->load->library('upload',$config);
```

Comment: Apparently `Epicureser1` does not have a `load` property. Either you are calling that on the wrong object, or that property has not yet been set when your code attempts to use it. That said, you've given us very little to work with here. We have no idea what "$this" is in the context except that its classname is probably `App\Controllers\Epicureser1`

Comment: why is that but its in the codeigniter documentation to call the library upload

Comment: My guess would be that `Epicureser1` doesnt extend the correct class or is missing a trait that is supposed to add that property. But without seeing the code from `Epicureser1` its hard to tell. Perhaps if you post the code for `Epicureser1` (at least the top part) we could discern a bit more.

Comment: If you're using Codeigniter 4, the super object `$this`, which was used for loading every kind of library, models, etc... has been removed. You should take a look at https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_4xx.html even it's not fully complete it will guide you through main changes.

Comment: yeah i am using codeigniter 4 but how can i use it to get the email and upload libraries

Answer (score 2):

The code your are showing there is not a part of Codeigniter 4 but Codeigniter 3.

That was the old way of uploading a file. If uploading a file is what you are trying to achived that can be done by using the IncomingRequest Class.

```
$files = $request->getFiles();

// Grab the file by name given in HTML form
if ($files->hasFile('uploadedFile'))
{
    $file = $files->getFile('uploadedfile');

    // Generate a new secure name
    $name = $file->getRandomName();

    // Move the file to it's new home
    $file->move('/path/to/dir', $name);

    echo $file->getSize('mb');      // 1.23
    echo $file->getExtension();     // jpg
    echo $file->getType();          // image/jpg
}
```

That is not really a Library. If by any chance what you're looking for is how to load libraries in Codeigniter 4, that is actually pretty easy. Let's say you want to use the Email Library.

First you should configure your email settings on **app/Config/Email.php**

To send an email your just need to access the email service:

```
$email = \Config\Services::email();

$email->setFrom('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$email->setTo('someone@example.com');
$email->setCC('another@another-example.com');
$email->setBCC('them@their-example.com');

$email->setSubject('Email Test');
$email->setMessage('Testing the email class.');

$email->send();
```

Now let's say what you want is to create a custom library, for that you should create your class inside your **app/Libraries** folder.

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class Custom
{

    public function myFunction()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now to load this library so you can use it's functions you should do the following.

```
$custom = new \App\Libraries\Custom();
$giveMeTrue = $custom->myFunction();
```

Like Vilar said in one of his comments:

> If you're using Codeigniter 4, the super object $this, which was used
> for loading every kind of library, models, etc... has been removed.
> You should take a look at
> codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_4xx.html even it's not
> fully complete it will guide you through main changes.

Comment: my aim is to save an base64 decoded image to a folder

Comment: This is an excellent answer because this basic explanation of libraries in the new Codeigniter 4 system is nowhere explained so clearly in the official documentation. A web search took me to this answer when I wanted a basic explanation of CI4 libraries.  Thank you VERY much for posting this answer. I wish I could upvote it 100+